# $\bigg(\frac{-2}{p}\bigg)= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if $p\equiv 1$ or $3 \mod 8$} \\ -1 & \text{ if $p\equiv 5$ or $7 \mod 8$} \\\end{cases}$

Tags: number-theory

Show that
$$\bigg(\frac{-2}{p}\bigg)=
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{ if $p\equiv 1$ or $3 \mod 8$} \\
-1 & \text{ if $p\equiv 5$ or $7 \mod 8$} \\\end{cases}$$

$\textbf{Proof:}$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\bigg(\frac{-2}{p}\bigg) &=\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{2}{p}\bigg)
=(-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}(-1)^\frac{p^2-1}{8}
=(-1)^\frac{4(p-1)+p^2-1}{8} \\
& =(-1)^\frac{p^2+4p-5}{8} 
=(-1)^\frac{(p-1)(p+5)}{8}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

$\textbf{Case $1$:}$ \begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(-1)^\frac{(p-1)(p+5)}{8}=1 & \iff \frac{(p-1)(p+5)}{8} \text{ is even}  \\
& \iff \frac{(p-1)(p+5)}{8}=2k \text{ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$}
\iff (p-1)(p+5)=16k \\
& \iff p-1=16k \text{ or } p+5=16k
\iff p=16k+1 \text{ or } p=16k-5 \\
& \iff p\equiv 1 \mod 8 \text{ or } p\equiv -5\equiv 3 mod 8
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

$\textbf{Case $2$:}$ \begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(-1)^\frac{(p-1)(p+5)}{8}=-1 & \iff \frac{(p-1)(p+5)}{8} \text{ is odd}  \\
& \iff \frac{(p-1)(p+5)}{8}=2k+1 \text{ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$}
\iff (p-1)(p+5)=16k+8 \\
& \iff p-1=16k+8 \text{ or } p+5=16k+8
\iff p=16k+9 \text{ or } p=16k+3 \\
& \iff p\equiv 1 \mod 8 \text{ or } p\equiv 3 \mod 8
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Am I right so far? If so how can I finish case 1? Note I am using Jacobi symbols.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the exponent.

Comment: Why do you say so?

Comment: Because $4(p-1)+p^2-1$  is not equal to $(p+1)(p+3)$.   Anyway, working with those formulas is (in my opinion) not the best way to find the answer.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: The revised version is OK in the first part. For the second part, you really don't need to do anything, since you have found when the exponent is even, the rest of the time it is odd. But you can verify directly. For example if $p\equiv 5\pmod{8}$ then $p=8k+5$ for some $k$, and $(p-1)(p+5)=(8k+4)(8k+10)$, which is divisible by $8$ but not by $16$.

Answer (score 1):

1) Recall that if $p$ is an odd prime, then $2$ is a QR of $p$ if $p\equiv  1$ or $7 \pmod{8}$, and $2$ is an NR of $p$ if $p\equiv 3$ or $5\pmod{8}$.

2) Also, $-1$ is a QR of $p$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and is an NR of $p$ if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.  This can be restated as $-1$ is a QR of $p$ if $p\equiv  1$ or $5 \pmod{8}$, and is an NR of $p$ if $p\equiv 3$ or $7\pmod{8}$.

Looking at 1) and 2), we see that $2$ and $-1$ are both QR of $p$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, and they are both NR of $p$ if $q\equiv 3\pmod{8}$. 
Thus $-2$ is a QR of $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 1$ or $3\pmod{8}$.

**Remark:** In the OP as revised, you have reduced the problem to finding out when $(p-1)(p+5)$ is divisible by $16$.

If $p=8k+1$, then $p-1$ is divisible by $8$, and $p+5$ is even, so $(p-1)(p+5)$ is divisible by $16$.

If $p=8k+3$, then $p+5$ is divisible by $8$, and $p-1$ is even, so $(p-1)(p+5)$ is divisible by $16$.

If $p=8k+5$, then $(p-1)(p+5)=(8k+4)(8k+10)$. The highest power of $2$ that divides $8k+4$ is $4$, and the highest power of $2$ that divides $8k+10$ is $2$, so the highest power of $2$ that divides the product is $(4)(2)=8$. It follows that the exponent $\frac{(p-1)(p+5)}{8}$ is odd.

The case $p=8k+7$ goes along lines similar to the case $8k+5$.

Note that your current *arguments* are incorrect. It is **not** true that $(p-1)(p+5)$ is divisible by $16$ if and only if $p-1$ is divisible by $16$ or $p+5$ is divisible by $16$. For each of $p-1$ and $p+5$ is even, so each makes a contribution to divisibility by powers of $2$.

Comment: But I keep getting 1 or 3 not 5 or 7?

Comment: You are finding that $(-1)^{\text{stuff}}$ is $1$  when $p\equiv 1$  or $3$, so $-2$ is a QR in those cases. In the remaining cases it is an NR. That is exactly what you were asked to do.

Comment: so im not suppose to get 5 or 7>

Comment: You are supposed to get $5$ or $7$ for when $-2$ is a non-residue. Your calculation for that part is not right.

Comment: where am i making a mistake?

Comment: Actually, you are making a mistake in both parts, but happened to get the right answer in the first part. I will add a remark to the post.